# Why a catch block cant be of type Object?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throwable

I am new to JAVA i am preparing for my OCP JP certification.

I have this doubt regarding exception handling

```
try{
        assert(false):"HI";
    }
catch(Throwable e){}
```

I know assert should not be handled but i am using this just for example. From what i know 
Object->Throwable ->Exception and Error

If i have Throwable or Exception or Error in the catch block it works but when i have object which is super class of all, eclipse shows me a compile time error.

Any reason why i cant have Object in catch block?

Comment: If I had "catch(Object)", then somewhere I would have to throw that Object. It just makes sense that if you're going to throw something... it should be throwable, and not all Objects are Throwable.

Comment: Its correct that every object cannot be thrown. But the objects which are thrown why can they not be referenced by a superclass

Comment: They can, it's called Throwable.

Comment: so anything above throwable cannot be referenced?

Comment: A Throwable object is one which is either a) Throwable or b) A subclass of a Throwable Object. Anything else cannot be throws nor caught

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only objects of type `Throwable` can be thrown or caught (which includes `Exception` and `Error`) in Java.

```
throw new Object(); // compiler error
throw new Integer(1); // compiler error
```

So it would be worthless to catch any old `Object`, because only `Throwable`s can be thrown.

Quoting from the [JLS, Section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20):

> Each class type used in the denotation of the type of an exception
>   parameter must be the class Throwable or a subclass of Throwable, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Comment: +1 The purpose of Throwable is to be the super class of all things which can be thrown.

Comment: so a superclass object cant hold these?

Comment: If an Object is designed to be thrown, then it will be Throwable. Perhaps if you describe a situation when you would want to throw a non-throwable object, we could show you

Comment: @user2626445 Sure, you can say `Object obj = new IllegalArgumentException();`, but you won't be able to `throw` it or `catch` it, because the compile time type is `Object`.

Comment: isn't catch block holding a reference. parent reference can be used for all the child objects right?

Comment: @user2626445 Yes, normally a parent reference can refer to a child object, but in this particular case, as I've quoted the JLS above, Java is not allowing anything higher up than `Throwable` in that `catch` statement, because it's not really a parameter as in a method; it's an _exception parameter_.

Comment: any general reason because its confusing when i read it and i did not understand much

Comment: its like a rule with no explanation

Comment: @rgettman It seems to be working just like parameters for a method. if I have "void method(Type arg)" and I have Object o = new Type(); I cannot pass o into method.

Answer (score 1):

According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

> The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language.
>   Only objects that are instances of this class (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the Java throw statement.
>   **Similarly, only this class or one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a catch clause**.

*`Object` is super class of  `Throwable`,not the subclass.*
Observe this class hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Throwable or all its subclasses

Comment: ya i know that but question was why object cant be there why is it designed that way?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JLS 14.20. The try statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> Each class type used in the denotation of the type of an exception
>   parameter must be the class Throwable or a subclass of Throwable, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Becaz in catch it expects throwable. Exception class or error class are throwable type as they are the subclass of Throwable. But Object class is not subclass of Throwable interface.

And important you can't throw an object. You can throw either an error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is saying that only throwable and its child class come into the catch block parenthesis which is right .
Now ,your doubt is :- why object cant be there why is it designed that way ?
i am breaking your question into 2 parts :-
1) why is it designed in that way ?
Answer :-because , we can only throw throwable class and its child class . So , it is designed to catch only these type of object only . 
2) why we cannot use Object class reference at the place of throwable or Exception Or Error ?

Answer :- It is very simple brother . throwable class is child class of Object class .ok . Now , we know that a Parent class can hold the reference of its child class but a child class can not hold the reference of its Parent class . Object class is parent class and throwable is child class and Catch block only accept throwable type . so , you can write throwable or Exception Or Error in catch block because throwable class is able to hold the reference of own and its subclasses . but throwable class can not hold the reference of its own Parent class i.e Object class . child class can not hold the reference of Parent class . I think this is the reason due to which we can not write Object type reference in catch block .